# Blend for Visual Studio doesn't show preview

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I started using Visual Studio Blend for making Windows 8 apps and I have noticed that the Live Preview doesn't load at all. What is the reason for this? I haven't been able to find anything in Google

Screenshot:

[image: Blend error]

Comment: have you installed the VS2012 Update 1? You can also ask this in the MSDN forums, so that MS employees can look at your issue.

Comment: It is stuck at Acquiring: Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Core Libraries (Bar is half filled) Applying: Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Core Libraries (Bar is full)

Comment: use this to download the complete files: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robcaron/archive/2012/11/26/how-to-install-visual-studio-2012-update-1-offline.aspx And run the Setup after getting all files.

Comment: Yeah just found that it is a web installer. Downloading the files now. will revert after installing

Comment: Btw how big are the files?

Comment: all files should be around 1GB.

Comment: How'd you install Blend for VS without fully installing VS 2012?

Comment: @MarkAllen The above discussion in the comments is for the update 1 package not the software itself

Comment: @magicandre1981 I installed Update 1. Same problem still.

Comment: aks this in the MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with some system DLL files. Doing a refresh helped to solved this problem. Thanks to Microsoft support and magicandre1981